# Use kwargs as key in dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a method which retrieves kwargs and future.
I would like to save a dictionary of kwargs to future for later processing future result with kwargs.

```
class ThreadPoolExecutorImproved(object):

def __init__(self, max_workers):
    self._executor = ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers)
    self._futures = {}

def __enter__(self):
    return self

def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_val, exc_tb):
    kwargs_to_exception = {}
    for kwargs, future in self._futures.iteritems():
        if future.exception():
            kwargs_to_exception[kwargs] = future.exception

    if kwargs_to_exception:
        raise ThreadPoolException(kwargs_to_exception)

def submit(self, fn, *args, **kwargs):
    future = self._executor.submit(fn, *args, **kwargs)
    key = tuple(kwargs.items())
    self._futures[key] = future
    return future
```

However, I get an error on the line `self.futures[key] = future`:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict' for python
```

why is it? I created a tuple from kwargs!

Comment: It means you have a **dictionary** in one of the **values** of `kwargs`.

Comment: I got it. so I would need each value to wrap it with a tuple?

Comment: you can indeed convert every dictionary to a tuple equivalent. Note that you will have to do this **recursively** since these dictionaries can also contain dictionaries and so on.

Comment: not that it is possible that the values are also *unhashable* types other than dictionaries (like `list`s or a generic `object`). So the problem is rather hard to solve in general, since it is not said these have *hashable* counterparts.

Comment: A cheap/hacky way (that will certainly not always work) would be to use the `repr` of the `kwargs` as key...

Comment: BTW, why are you using `kwargs` as the key in the first place? What if two functions are called with the same `kwargs`, or what if `kwargs` is empty?

Comment: Could you provide a complete working example? Now I it remains somewhat vague what you are doing. For example we don't know what `_executor.submit` is doing. Better yet, the variables `fn` and `args` don't seem so relevant? Finally, I would suggest you use an indentation of 4 characters to be consistent with the Python standard.

Comment: @TomdeGeus see the full code -  I am basically writing a new wrapper

Comment: The code is still not complete: I cannot copy/paste and run. To me it also remains vague what you ideal outcome is. But I would probably convert `_futures` into a list, initialized by `self._futures = []`, and use `_futures.append((future,kwargs))`. But possibly storing by thread-id is more to you liking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The typical workaround for this situation is to use `future` as a key;
Your code

```
key = tuple(kwargs.items())
self._futures[key] = future
```

Migrate to

```
self._futures[future] = tuple(kwargs.items())
```

And when you want to process `self._futures`, you can just iterate this

```
for future, kw in self._futures:
    # check kw
    # do your stuff
```